# Testing an Async function using Jest / Enzyme

Tags: async-await, jestjs, enzyme

Trying run a test case for the following:

```
async getParents() {
 const { user, services, FirmId } = this.props;
 let types = await Models.getAccounts({ user, services, firmId: FirmId });
 let temp = types.map((type) => {   
     if(this.state.Parent_UID && this.state.Parent_UID.value === type.Account_UID) {
       this.setState({Parent_UID: {label: type.AccountName, value: type.Account_UID}})
    }           
     return {
       label: type.AccountName,
       value: type.Account_UID,
     }
   })
 this.setState({ParentOptions: temp});
}
```

here is what i have so far for my test:

```
beforeEach(() => wrapper = mount(<MemoryRouter keyLength={0}><AccountForm {...baseProps} /></MemoryRouter>));

it('Test getParents function ',async() => {
 wrapper.setProps({
   user:{},
   services:[],
   FirmId:{},
 })
 wrapper.find('AccountForm').setState({
  SourceOptions:[[]],
  Parent_UID: [{
  label:[],
  value:[],
 }],
    });
wrapper.update();
  await 
expect(wrapper.find('AccountForm').instance().getParents()).toBeDefined()
});
```

If i try to make this ToEqual() it expects a promise and not anobject, what else could I add into this test to work properly.

Goal: Make sure the functions gets called correctly. The test is passing at the moment and has a slight increase on test coverage.
Using Jest and Enzyme for React Js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put the await before the async method, like:

`await wrapper.find('AccountForm').instance().getParents()`

and compare if the state was changed.

In another way, if can mock your API request, because this is a test, then you do not need the correct API, but know if the function calls the API correctly and if the return handling is correct.

And, you cand spy the function like:
`const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.find('AccountForm').instance(), 'getParents');`

and campare if the function was called if they are triggered by some action:
`expect(spy).toBeCalled()`

Comment: Carlos, i get the following error when I try the second option :

Comment: expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()

    Expected mock function to have been called.

Comment: When you spy, the function is mocked and wrapped by jest.fn(), so when you expect to have been called, must be a jest.fn() function. Instead of using ```toBeCalled``` try ```toHaveBeenCalled```. But your error is because the function was not wrapped by jest.

Comment: Carlos, so what exactly i need to change or add in order to make this function to work ?